# How to join three strings to a single datetime value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime, join

i have to write a code which can join three string values from textboxes to a single datetime value.

For example: textbox1.text is my day value . Think, i write 05.
             textbox2.text is my mounth value . Think, i write 06.
             textbox3.text is my year value. Think,i write 1991.

Then i have to join this three values. it becomes like this 05.06.1991 so i can insert this value to my database. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: new DateTime(textbox1.text, textbox2.text, textbox3.text)

Comment: i try this;  DateTime mydate= new DateTime();
        
        tarih.AddDays(Double.Parse(txtbox.text.ToString()));
        tarih.AddMonths(int.Parse(txtbox.Text.ToString()));
        tarih.AddYears(int.Parse(txtbox.Text.ToString()));

Comment: Why not just use a DateTimePicker to enter the date; not only will it avoid date parsing issues, but it will be easier for the user.

Answer (score 7):

Check the DateTime constructor one of them has `DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)` signature which equals `DateTime(year, month, day)` so your code must be

```
DateTime input = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtMonth.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtDay.Text));
```

Cheers.